# @Schedule causing DuplicateServiceException

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a simple method in my JAX-WS project that, for the moment, prints to the console every second. I found [this](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_16) simple guide and I have tried to implement it to my current working project.

My `TimerService.java` looks like this:

```
package brass.ducks.controller;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class TimerService {
    @EJB
    HelloService helloService;

    @Schedule(second="*/1", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
    public void doWork(){
        System.out.println("timer: " + helloService.sayHello());
    }
}
```

And my `HelloService.java` looks like this:

```
package brass.ducks.controller;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class HelloService {
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello from control: " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

I noted that the tutorial mentioned something about how to deploy? Would this be covered by just deploying the project on my local WildFly server or does it require something else?

Here is my stacktrace too:

```
14:53:03,672 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
14:53:04,119 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
14:53:04,239 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
14:53:06,683 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment BrassDucks.war
14:53:06,708 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found BrassDucks.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called BrassDucks.war.dodeploy
14:53:06,829 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
14:53:06,860 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
14:53:06,873 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
14:53:06,981 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
14:53:07,003 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
14:53:07,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
14:53:07,063 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
14:53:07,072 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
14:53:07,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
14:53:07,359 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
14:53:07,373 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
14:53:07,378 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
14:53:07,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.2.Final)
14:53:07,470 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
14:53:07,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.4.Final
14:53:07,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
14:53:07,530 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
14:53:07,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
14:53:07,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
14:53:07,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
14:53:08,133 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
14:53:08,154 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
14:53:08,183 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
14:53:08,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
14:53:08,238 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
14:53:08,882 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
14:53:09,092 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO.
14:53:09,237 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar")
14:53:09,253 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "BrassDucks.war" (runtime-name: "BrassDucks.war")
14:53:09,280 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
14:53:09,374 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\journal,bindingsDirectory=C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\largemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\paging)
14:53:09,587 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
14:53:09,823 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
14:53:10,757 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
14:53:10,824 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
14:53:10,835 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
14:53:10,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
14:53:10,865 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
14:53:10,868 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
14:53:11,045 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
14:53:11,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
14:53:11,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
14:53:11,358 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
14:53:11,544 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
14:53:11,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MySqlNorthwindDS]
14:53:11,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/BrassDucksDS]
14:53:11,634 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MySqlEquitiesDS]
14:53:12,241 INFO  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (management I/O-2) WFLYPRT0057:  cancelled task by interrupting thread Thread[management-handler-thread - 1,5,management-handler-thread]
14:53:12,479 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
14:53:12,483 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
14:53:12,483 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
14:53:12,484 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
14:53:12,614 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221007: Server is now live
14:53:12,615 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 1.1.0.wildfly-011 [nodeID=ad393a41-759e-11e6-8402-b9b09451d246] 
14:53:12,660 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
14:53:12,696 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.Tasks
14:53:12,726 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
14:53:12,731 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
14:53:12,737 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
14:53:12,796 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
14:53:12,895 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-7) Resource adaptor started
14:53:12,895 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-7) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
14:53:12,897 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
14:53:12,898 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
14:53:15,665 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment BrassDucks.war
14:53:15,797 INFO  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (management I/O-2) WFLYPRT0057:  cancelled task by interrupting thread Thread[management-handler-thread - 1,5,management-handler-thread]
14:53:15,811 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.3.Final
14:53:15,930 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'BrassDucksDAO' in deployment unit 'deployment "BrassDucks.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/BrassDucks/BrassDucksDAO!brass.ducks.model.BrassDucksDAO
    java:app/BrassDucks/BrassDucksDAO!brass.ducks.model.BrassDucksDAO
    java:module/BrassDucksDAO!brass.ducks.model.BrassDucksDAO
    java:global/BrassDucks/BrassDucksDAO
    java:app/BrassDucks/BrassDucksDAO
    java:module/BrassDucksDAO

14:53:15,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'Trader' in deployment unit 'deployment "BrassDucks.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/BrassDucks/Trader!brass.ducks.model.Trader
    java:app/BrassDucks/Trader!brass.ducks.model.Trader
    java:module/Trader!brass.ducks.model.Trader
    java:global/BrassDucks/Trader
    java:app/BrassDucks/Trader
    java:module/Trader

14:53:15,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'HelloService' in deployment unit 'deployment "BrassDucks.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/BrassDucks/HelloService!brass.ducks.controller.HelloService
    java:app/BrassDucks/HelloService!brass.ducks.controller.HelloService
    java:module/HelloService!brass.ducks.controller.HelloService
    java:global/BrassDucks/HelloService
    java:app/BrassDucks/HelloService
    java:module/HelloService

14:53:15,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'TimerService' in deployment unit 'deployment "BrassDucks.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/BrassDucks/TimerService!brass.ducks.controller.TimerService
    java:app/BrassDucks/TimerService!brass.ducks.controller.TimerService
    java:module/TimerService!brass.ducks.controller.TimerService
    java:global/BrassDucks/TimerService
    java:app/BrassDucks/TimerService
    java:module/TimerService

14:53:16,333 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."BrassDucks.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."BrassDucks.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "BrassDucks.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0052: Failed to install component TimerService
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.module.BrassDucks.BrassDucks.TimerService is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:158)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:235)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:768)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:317)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deployComponent(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:101)
    ... 6 more

14:53:16,377 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "BrassDucks.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"BrassDucks.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"BrassDucks.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"BrassDucks.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0052: Failed to install component TimerService
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.module.BrassDucks.BrassDucks.TimerService is already registered"},
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"BrassDucks.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"BrassDucks.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"BrassDucks.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"BrassDucks.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
14:53:16,427 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar")
14:53:16,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "BrassDucks.war" (runtime-name : "BrassDucks.war")
14:53:16,493 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."BrassDucks.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."BrassDucks.war".batch.environment, service jboss.deployment.unit."BrassDucks.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."BrassDucks.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."BrassDucks.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "BrassDucks.war"

14:53:16,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:53:16,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:53:16,783 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started (with errors) in 13851ms - Started 395 of 689 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 401 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
14:53:16,887 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment BrassDucks.war (runtime-name: BrassDucks.war) in 60ms
14:53:17,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "BrassDucks.war" (runtime-name: "BrassDucks.war")
14:53:17,088 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."BrassDucks.war".INSTALL

14:53:21,595 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found BrassDucks.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called BrassDucks.war.dodeploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following steps:

These are the steps I followed to resolve the issue.

1.Stop the Server.

2.Go to deployment path.

3.Manually deleted the existing project in deployment folder.

4.Restarted the server

5.Deploy the application again.

because From the error, it looks like ".BrassDucks.BrassDucks.TimerService" already deployed on the server